# Loop input value to list until correct in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to loop the input of a user **until** the correct value is equal to one item in the list.

```
name = ['peter', 'jay']

user = str(input("Enter UserID: "))

if user == name:
print ("welcome back" + user")

else:
print ("wrong input, you have 3 more tries, please try again")
```

Comment: You want `in` not `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will go like this,

```
name = ['peter', 'jay']
for i in range(0,4):
    user = str(input("Enter UserID: "))
    if user in name: 
        print ("welcome back " + user)
        break
    elif i !=3: 
        print ("wrong input, you have", (3-i) , "more tries, please try again")
    else: 
         print ("wrong input, you have no more chances")
```

Comment: thanks so much, for learning purpose: if i would want to do infinite loop till answer becomes correct?

Comment: If you want to do an infinite loop, the answer would look like this `name = ['peter', 'jay']
while True:
    user = str(input("Enter UserID: "))
    if user in name: 
        print ("welcome back " + user)
        break
    else: 
         print ("wrong input,please try again!")`